# Modal not displaying correctly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, modal

I created an Aura Component for our Lightning Opportunity page that will replace our URL hacking for classic to pull information to a new asset record. I added a Modal to select the Record type before firing force:createRecord. createRecord displays it's modal correctly, but it is displaying the record type Modal incorrectly.

[image]

cmp Code:

```
    <div role="dialog" 
         tabindex="-1" 
         aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01"
         aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1"
         class="slds-modal slds-modal_small"
         aura:id="myModal">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <div class="slds-modal__header">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button--icon-inverse"
                            title="Close" 
                            onclick="{!c.closeModal}">
                        X<span class="slds-assistive-text">Cancel</span>
                    </button>
                    <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading--medium">New Asset</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                        <div class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-large-size--1-of-2">
                             <div class="slds-align--absolute-center">Select a Record Type</div>                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-large-size--1-of-2">
                            <ui:inputSelect aura:id="selectid">
                                <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstOfRecordType}" var="contact">                            
                                    <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!contact}" label="{!contact}"  />
                                </aura:iteration>
                            </ui:inputSelect>
                        </div>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                    </div>                   
                </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.closeModal}">Cancel</lightning:button>
                    <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.newAsset}">Next</lightning:button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-backdrop" aura:id="myModal-Back"/>
```

Controller:

```
closeModal: function(component, event, helper) {
   //find modal using aura id
    var modal = component.find("myModal");
    var modalBackdrop = component.find("myModal-Back");

   // Now add and remove class
    $A.util.removeClass(modal, 'slds-fade-in-open');
    $A.util.removeClass(modalBackdrop, 'slds-fade-in-open');
    },
 
   openModal: function(component, event, helper) {
   //find modal using aura id
    var modal = component.find("myModal");
    var modalBackdrop = component.find("myModal-Back");

   // Now add and remove class
    $A.util.addClass(modal, 'slds-fade-in-open');
    $A.util.addClass(modalBackdrop, 'slds-fade-in-open');
   },
```

CSS:

```
.THIS .slds-backdrop {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

It's not the backdrop, as I set that to Blue, so I'm not sure what is causing this.

Comment: can you inspect the elements in your browser? this will give you a better Idea of what may be going on. For example, CSS issue, or the element is simply not rendered, etc, tec..

Comment: Turns out I'm an idiot. i set the background of the component to white because i was trying to set the background of the component card. it made everything white.

Comment: 

Answer (score 0):

Stepping back a bit on this: why not use a URL with pre-filled fields in Lightning?

This approach in classic was common, but unsupported, so I understand the hesitancy. But in Lightning, as of the Spring 20 release (last year), this is an actually supported approach. [Source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.links_useful_custom_buttons_create_record_dfv.htm&type=5)

```
/lightning/o/[OBJECT_API_NAME]/new?defaultFieldValues=
    Name={!URLENCODE('value')},
    Custom_Field_Api_Name__c={!URLENCODE('value')}
```

add `useRecordTypeCheck=1` if you don't want to skip the record type selection screen

```
/lightning/o/[OBJECT_API_NAME]/new?useRecordTypeCheck=1&defaultFieldValues=
    Name={!URLENCODE('value')},
    Custom_Field_Api_Name__c={!URLENCODE('value')}
```

Comment: I did want to do this at first. It would have been waaaaay simpler, but I ran into some issues with date codes and lookup fields not parsing. I tried troubleshooting, but i couldn't get them to work

Comment: For what its worth, some of the things that tripped me up:                                         
 - Field Names are case sensitive ("Name" will work, "name" will not)                    
 - Dates expect the following format: YYYY-MM-DD. (eg: Date_Field__c=2021-02-01)

Comment: Not sure what your issue with lookups were, but it works for me using the __c version of the field name and the 18 digit version of the record ID